# Log4j2 and Jboss EAP 7: Exceptions logging

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j2, jboss-eap-7

I have a web app running on `Jboss EAP 7.0.2`. In my app I want to use `Log4j2` for logging. So, I added `log4j2` and `log4j-slf4j-impl` as dependencies:

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.7'
```

Put file **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Created **log4j2.xml** (I omit its content, but it writes the log to the file *lea.log*).

Also, I have **TestRestService**

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestRestService {
    private Logger logger  = LogManager.getFormatterLogger(TestRestService.class);
    private org.slf4j.Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestRestService.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/logger")
    public void testLogger() {
        logger.info("Log4j2 log");
        slf4jLogger.info("SLF4J log");
        throw new RuntimeException("Test");
    }
}
```

This test method writes to `lea.log`:

```
2016-11-07 15:25:37.673 [default task-7] INFO  ru.rshb.test.TestRestService - Log4j2 log
2016-11-07 15:25:37.673 [default task-7] INFO  ru.rshb.test.TestRestService - SLF4J log
```

but it doesn't log the exception!

In server.log I see:

```
2016-11-07 15:25:37,673 INFO  [stdout] (default task-7) INFO  - Log4j2 log

2016-11-07 15:25:37,673 INFO  [stdout] (default task-7) INFO  - SLF4J log

2016-11-07 15:25:37,674 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005023: Exception handling request to /lea-core/rest/test/logger: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test
...
```

---

**Questions:**

1. How can I direct all messages and exceptions that happened in my app to lea.log (my log4j2 log file)?
2. Does it suppose to log to server.log file even if I excluded the logging subsystem from my deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're throwing the exception from the REST endpoint and not handling it. Therefore the server handles it for you which cannot log to your applications log configuration.

Excluding the logging subsystem will stop your deployment from being processed by the logging subsystem. (Which does mean you don't need those module exclusions). However the server itself will still use the configuration from the logging subsystem.

If you want to catch exceptions of a specific type you could use a [`javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to log the exception then create a response for it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
It doesn't appeal to me to catch all exceptions in my app. What I'm trying to achieve is to employ Log4j2's routing logging functionality (or SiftingAppernder, as it's called in Logback). From my understanding, there is no sifting functionality in the default logging subsystem. So, I guess, the best option for me will be enabling Logback as the server logging framework (like it described [here](http://blog.anotheria.net/devops/enable-logback-in-jboss/), for example). Is that right?

Comment: That may work for WildFly itself, but if other dependencies are using log4j or JUL you might not get those log messages directed to logback.

Comment: I find a bit strange, not to be able to use log4j2 in EAP !

Comment: You can use log4j2 in EAP in your application. The server components will not use log4j2 however.